# How to separate design and logic of Repeater in QML

Tags: qt, qml

When using QML, Qt Creator advises to separate design and logic into 2 QML files, e.g. a File.qml and FileForm.ui.qml, the former for logic, the latter for design. It can only show a file in visual designer if it does not contain complex code, like function calls or {} code blocks (I'm using Qt creator 4.5.2 that comes with Ubuntu 18.04).

Now for the question: how do I move complex code out of ui.qml when I use Repeater and its delegates?

Example:

My `FileForm.ui.qml` looks like this:

```
import "displayutils.js" as Utils

RowLayout {
    property alias rr: rr
    property alias tt: tt
    Repeater {
        id: rr
        Text {
            id: tt
            text: "text: "+ Utils.fmtTemp(modelData.temp)+" / "+Utils.fmtPressure(modelData.pressure)
        }
    }
}
```

I instantiate it in `File.qml` like this:

```
File {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        rr.model = ... // some model from C++ code, does not matter.
    }    
}
```

Now, Qt Creator does not want to open `FileForm.ui.qml` file because of complex formatting of text and I have to move it to File.qml. How do I do this correctly? Whatever I tried, I loose modelData object from Repeater. I tried various variants of this:

```
File {
    tt.text = someFunction(modelData)
    Component.onCompleted: {
        rr.model = ... // some model from C++ code, does not matter.
    }    
}
```

Comment: I stopped using this separation long time ago. But possibly you can get around this by creating a QML specifically for the delegate: In that case you can put that in the Repeater and only have to assign `modelData` as a property to the delegate-type and inside the delegate, you can use the function

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But my Qt creator gives "Qt emulation layer crashed" in this case. It's either my layout is too complex (which I doubt) or it's buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this separation very helpful and use it all of the time. You can do it in this case by separating out the Repeater's children like this:

RepeaterTextForm.ui.qml:

```
Text {}
```

RepeaterText.qml:

```
import "displayutils.js" as Utils 

RepeaterTextForm {
    text: (
        "text: " + 
        Utils.fmtTemp(modelData.temp) + 
        " / " + 
        Utils.fmtPressure(modelData.pressure)
    )
}
```

FileForm.ui.qml:

```
RowLayout {
    property alias rr: rr
    Repeater {
        id: rr
        RepeaterText {}
    }
}
```

File.qml:

```
File {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        rr.model = ... // some model from C++ code, does not matter.
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How does it look in Qt Designer? Does it show the deepest Text element when opening FileForm.ui.qml? I'll check it myself in a few days but in case you already know.

Comment: Just saw your comment. It should look and render all components as expected in Design mode.

Comment: Tried that, QML engine crashes on my PC somewhy. I actually understand it - if the engine does not understand function calls, it won't understand them if they are burried deep in the include tree as well...

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll make a reproducible crashing example out of your answer.